# Function pointer in python DLL

Tags: python, c, dll, callback, function-pointers

I am writing a Python script for C code via DLL file.
I don't know how to call the callback function in Python.
I found a lot of useful things on the internet but I still miss a lot.
I have the following code in C:

```
typedef uint16(*CALLBACK_1)(DATA *data);
typedef uint16(*CALLBACK_2)(DATA *data);
uint16 end_function(OPT *opt, CALLBACK_1 function_1, CALLBACK_2 function_2, DATA *data);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would pretty much take the whole Python C-API documentation to explain. So please, start there.
https://docs.python.org/3.8/c-api/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for examples of callbacks in Python. I have found this link: https://gist.github.com/mchung/76d774879245b355e8bff95f9172f9f8 with the code as follows:

```
# Example of using callbacks with Python
#
# To run this code
#   1. Copy the content into a file called `callback.py`
#   2. Open Terminal and type: `python /path/to/callback.py`
#   3. Enter

def add(numbers, callback):
    results = []
    for i in numbers:
        results.append(callback(i))
    return results

def add2(number):
    return number + 2

def mul2(number):
    return number * 2

print add([1,2,3,4], add2) #=> [3, 4, 5, 6]
print add([1,2,3,4], mul2) #=> [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Take a look at the function called `add`. It gets two parameters: `numbers` and `callback`. Numbers is an array of `numbers` and `callback` is a function. This function creates an array called `results` as an empty array and loops through `numbers`, calling `callback(i)` and appending the result to `results`. As you can see, callback can be `called` inside a function. In the last two lines two separate functions are passed to `add`, which will act as `callback` inside the function.

Comment: Thank you! I understand that, what I don't understand is how to call this function (end_function) in python since I should define functions (function_1 and function_2) and I don't know how to do it in the ctypes library.

Comment: @vex maybe this link helps you: https://www.journaldev.com/31907/calling-c-functions-from-python